# How to check, if acrobat.exe is really from the Adobe install package?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, windows-installer

I am looking for a (scriptable) approach to identify, if the file acrobat.exe is really the original file from the latest Adobe Acrobat DC installer or if it is one from an older Acrobat install or even a tampered one?

Of course I can check the file-signature, but this is only telling me, that the file is from Adobe, but not if its the latest version which belongs to the official installer.

I downloaded the official setup-file from the Adobe webpage and extracted that with 7zip and could find an MSI database file in it, but there is no such acrobat.exe-entry in the files-table of that MSI file. Now I am wondering where the file acrobat.exe does even come from.

Any help (or idea) here is more than welcome.

Comment: Download from Adobe.com and let the installed package update and it will be fine. Millions of users do this.

Comment: Thanky you for your input, but that does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already extracted the MSI package, you now can peek inside it
to verify that your `acrobat.exe` is identical.

You will find MSI Viewers and extractors in the article
[6 Ways to View and Extract MSI Files: Best MSI Extractors](https://whatsoftware.com/how-to-view-and-extract-contents-from-a-msi-file/).

This site does not allow product recommendations.

Comment: As I said, that file is not listed in the files-table of the MSI. I have no clue how Adobe creates that file on the fly.

Comment: I tested one product from the list on a random MSI and it worked, so it seems that your MSI is in a non-standard format. The software it carries must be packaged differently, if none of these products can handle it.

Comment: Thank you for testing this.  My question is not around a random MSI, but exactly the Acrobat DC installer. That MSI has not the file acrobat.exe in its file-table.